# How to apply column-wise logic to a dataframe?

Tags: r, date, tidyverse, data-wrangling

I'd like to mutate a new column and populate it with the first column/year that has a 0.

Consider the following dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(pred2014 = c(0,0,1), pred2015 = c(0,0,1),
                 pred2016 = c(0,1,1), measured2017 = c(0,0,1))
df
```

In this example, row 1 would be pred2014, row2 = pred2016 and row3 = NA.

Comment: Shouldn't row2 = pred2014?

Comment: Yes, good catch @ThomasIsCoding - bad example on my part, but akrun's solution works exactly as I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `max.col`

```
nm1 <- names(df)[max.col(df == 0, 'first') * NA^!rowSums(df == 0)]
nm1
#[1] "pred2014" "pred2016" NA
```

---

Or using `apply`

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) names(x)[which(x == 0)[1]])
```